# Find the polar set of a convex cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

I am stuck with the following question:

> Given the convex cone $$K = \{x \in \mathbb R^n : x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \cdots \geq x_n \geq 0\}$$ determine the polar set of $K$, which we denote by $K^{*}$.

---

I know that $K$ is a convex cone, which is easy to proof. I also know from our lecture, that $K^{*}$ is again a convex cone and
$$K^{*}=\{y\in \mathbb{R^n}: \langle x,y\rangle \leq 0\ \forall x\in K\},$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the inner product.

It's quite obvious, that all $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $y_i\leq0\  \forall i\in[n]$ are in $K^{*}$.
But there have to be some more inequalities or easier ways to determine $K^{*}$.
Do you have any hints/suggestions?

Comment: $K$ is actually just $A \cdot \mathbb{R}^n_+$, where $A$ is a certain invertible matrix. Does this help?

Comment: If I would find out more about A, this would help a lot! Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Do you have any hints for A? It might be too obvious for me...

Comment: Think I got it :-)

Comment: Good. Then post your answer, and get points! :-)

Comment: @MichaelGrant can you please help me with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449707/finding-the-polar-cone-of-the-given-cone-that-consists-of-vectors-in-mathbbr ? It is also a polar cone problem and not very many people on MSE answer these types of questions. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with Michael Grant's hint, the solution should be the following:
$Let A\in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ be the upper triangular matrix consisting of $1$'s. Then $K=A\cdot \mathbb{R^{n}_+}$. A is invertiable, and the following proposition can be easily shown:
$$(MX)^* = M^{-T}X^*\hspace{1mm}  where \hspace{1mm} M\in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}} \hspace{1mm} invertiable$$
So for the solution of our problem, we just have to find out $A^{-T}$ and determine what ($\mathbb{R^{n}_+})^*$ is, which is not too difficult, since for $ y\in R^{n}:{<y,x>}\leq 0 \forall \hspace{1mm} x\in \mathbb{R^{n}_+}$, so $y\in\mathbb{R^{n}_-}$.