# Finding the polar cone of the given cone

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone

Given a closed convex cone $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the cone $K_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is defined by $$ K_{2} = \{ y = (y^{1}, y^{2}, \cdots , y^{m}): y^{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\, i= 1, \cdots , m, \, y^{1} + y^{2} + \cdots + y^{m} \in D \} $$

I need to describe its polar cone $K_{2}^{\circ}$.

Recall that for a given cone $C$, its polar cone $C^{\circ}$ is defined to be the set of all $x$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle \leq 0$ for all $y \in C$.

So, if $y \in K_{2}$, then $$ y = \begin{pmatrix} y^{1}, & y^{2},& \cdots, & y^{m}\end{pmatrix} \\ = \begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} y_{1}^{1} & y_{2}^{1} & \cdots y_{n}^{1} \end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} y_{1}^{2} & y_{2}^{2} & \cdots y_{n}^{2} \end{pmatrix},\cdots ,\begin{pmatrix} y_{1}^{m} & y_{2}^{m} & \cdots y_{n}^{m} \end{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}.$$

So, I need to find the set of all $x$ such that when I take the inner product of $x$ and $y$, I get a value $\leq 0$.

My first problem is that I'm not sure if I have even expressed a general set in $K_{2}$ correctly here. Secondly, I would think that perhaps I should take the inner product of a general $y$ with a general $x$, set the result $\leq 0$ and then try to solve for what the components of $x$ are, but as I am not sure even what a general $x$ should look like, I am at a loss as to how this should be done.

If this is not the correct approach to finding the polar of this cone, what is the correct approach? Beyond the inner product definition of a polar cone (which in terms of angles between things, means that $x$ and $y$ make an obtuse angle with each other), I don't know much about how to go about finding them.

I sincerely thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: I am more used to the terminology 'dual cone'.

Comment: @copper.hat that's not the same thing. The dual cone is the orthogonal complement of the polar cone.

Comment: The dual cone is the negative of the polar cone.

Comment: @copper.hat correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an initial observation, but not a full solution.  Changing notation slightly, 
$$K_2 = \{ Y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & \cdots & y_m \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{n \times m} \mid y_1 + \cdots + y_m \in D \}.$$ 
(Here $y_i$ is the $i$th column of the matrix $Y$.) A matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ belongs to $K_2^\circ$ if and only if 
$$\langle X, Y \rangle = \text{tr}(Y X^T) = \text{tr}(y_1 x_1^T + \cdots + y_m x_m^T) \leq 0 \text{ for all } Y \in K_2.$$ If $x_1 = \cdots = x_m = x \in D^\circ$, then 
$$\langle X, Y \rangle = \text{tr}( (y_1+\cdots+y_m)^T x) = x^T(y_1 + \cdots + y_m) \leq 0,
$$ 
so $X \in K_2^\circ$.
This shows that $S = \{ \begin{bmatrix} x & \cdots & x \end{bmatrix} \mid x \in D^\circ\} \subset K_2^\circ$.

We can conjecture that in fact $S = K_2^\circ$.  We still need to show containment in the other direction.

By the way, sometimes once you have guessed what the polar cone is, it turns out to be easier to show that $S^\circ = K_2$.  If it can be shown that $S^\circ = K_2$, which I suspect is straightforward, it will follow that $S = K_2^\circ$.

---

Let's attempt to show that $S^\circ \subset K_2$.  So, suppose that $Y \in S^\circ$.  From the definition of $S^\circ$, we have that $\langle Y, X \rangle \leq 0$ for all $X \in S$. Using the definition of $S$, we see that
$$
\tag{1}\langle Y, \begin{bmatrix} x & \cdots x \end{bmatrix} \rangle \leq 0
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$.
We have hoping to conclude that $Y \in K_2$.  In other words, we are hoping to conclude that the columns of $Y$ sum to $0$.  Does this follow somehow from the fact that the inequality (1) holds **for all** $x \in \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: so it IS  a matrix? I wasn't even sure what sets in $K_{1}$ were supposed to look like.

Comment: I think that we should view $K_2$ as being a subset of $\mathbb R^{n \times m}$, and so $K_2^\circ$ is also a subset of $\mathbb R^{n \times m}$.

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming familiarity with the Frobenius inner product on $\mathbb R^{n \times m}$ defined by $\langle A, B \rangle = \text{tr}(A^T B) = \text{tr}(B^T A)$.  Note that $\text{tr}(A^T B) = \text{tr}(B A^T)$ for all $A, B$.

Comment: I've seen that defined in my text. One more thing, why did you think $x_{1}=\cdots = x_{m} = x $ would do the job? And how did you know that $x \in D^{\circ}$ even?

Comment: I'm conjecturing that $S = \{ \begin{bmatrix} x & \cdots & x \end{bmatrix} \mid x \in D^\circ\}$ is equal to $K_2^\circ$.  It's easy to show that $S \subset K_2^\circ$ (this is shown above), but hopefully it's also possible to show that $K_2^\circ \subset S$.

Comment: also how do you know that $x^{T} (y_{1} + \cdots + y_{m})\leq 0$? I'm sorry for all the follow-up questions, but I just want to understand.

Comment: but intuitively, why did you conjecture that?

Comment: We know that $y_1 + \cdots + y_m \in D$, and we are assuming that $x \in D^\circ$, so it follows that $\langle x, y_1 + \cdots + y_m \rangle \leq 0$.

Comment: Intuitively, I wrote out the condition that $\langle X, Y \rangle = \text{tr}(Y X^T) = \text{tr}(y_1 x_1^T + \cdots + y_m x_m^T) \leq 0$, and I asked myself, how could I choose $X$ to make this be true?  Somehow we need to use the fact that $y_1 + \cdots + y_m \in D$.  Well, if all the column vectors $x_i$ are equal, we can factor them out, and we are left with $ \text{tr}(x^T(y_1  + \cdots + y_m )) = \langle y_1 + \cdots + y_m, x \rangle \leq 0$, and this suggests that we want $x$ to belong to $D^\circ$.  It helps to have internalized matrix block multiplication so individual steps are easy.

Comment: going in the other direction, let $W \in K_{2}^{\circ}$. Then, $\langle W, Y \rangle = tr(Y\,W^{T}) = tr(y_{1}w_{1}^{T}+y_{2}w_{2}^{T}+\cdots + y_{m}w_{m}^{T}) \leq 0$. Now, is there anything about this here that would allow us to conclude that $W$ must also be in $S$?

Comment: Now that we've conjectured that $K_2^\circ = S$, I would be inclined to attempt to proceed by proving that $S^\circ = K_2$.  I suspect this will be easier, although I'm not sure.  If it can be shown that $S^\circ = K_2$, it will follow that $S = K_2^\circ$.

Comment: since I don't really know how to determine polar cones of any cone, I doubt it. All I know is that when you take the inner product of a vector from a set with a vector from the set that is supposed to be its polar cone, the result is supposed to be $\leq 0$. And when the elements are something like $[x \,\, x\,\, \cdots \, \, x]$ I'm even less confident.

Comment: A next step would be to try to show that $S^\circ \subset K_2$.  In other words, if $Y \in S^\circ$, then $Y \in K_2$.  So to do this, we could start by writing out explicitly (and carefully and precisely) what it means to say that $Y \in S^\circ$.

Comment: and showing that $S^{\circ} \subset K_{2}$ together with $S \subset K_{2}$ is equivalent to showing that $S=K_{2}^{\circ}$?

Comment: again I apologize for asking so many follow-up questions.Just after you've shown that $S^{\circ} \subset K_{2}$, then what? I also don't know explicitly or carefully or precisely what it means to say that $Y \subset S^{\circ}$. This whole $^{\circ} $ thing is a bit of a problem for me. Except that if $X \subset S$ then $<X,Y> \leq 0$.

Comment: A common strategy to show that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal is to first show that $A \subset B$ and then to show that $B \subset A$.  In our case, we want to show that $S^\circ = K_2$.  So, we can attempt to do that by first showing that $S^\circ \subset K_2$ and then showing that $K_2 \subset S^\circ$.

Comment: I updated the question to provide some more steps towards showing that $S^\circ \subset K_2$.

Comment: there's a theorem I found in my text: "Assume that $C$ is a closed convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Let $K = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: Ax \in C \}$. Then, $K$ is a closed convex cone and $K^{\circ} = \{A^{T}\lambda: \lambda \in C^{\circ}\}$." Can we use this to help us, or does it not apply?

Comment: @ALannister That's a very interesting theorem.  Which textbook and which page is it?

Comment: it's called Nonlinear Optimization by Andrzej Ruszczynski. It's Theorem 2.28, on p. 29 (p. 29 in the ebook, in the physical copy, I'm not sure what the page is, but the theorem number should be the same).

Comment: You can use that theorem, good idea.  In this approach, I think we should now view $K_2$ as being a subset of $\mathbb R^{mn}$, so when we say that $y = (y_1,\ldots, y_m)$ what we mean is that $y$ is the column vector you get by stacking the column vectors $y_1,\ldots,y_m$.  Now, the condition $y_1 + \cdots + y_m \in D$ can be expressed as $Ay \in D$, for a certain matrix $A$.  Do you see what matrix $A$ is so that $Ay = y_1 + \cdots + y_m$?

Comment: would it be a matrix of basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$?

Comment: @ALannister Something like that, can you write it more explicitly?  We have that $y$ is a column vector in $\mathbb R^{mn}$, and we want it to be true that $Ay = y_1 + \cdots + y_m$.  What shape should $A$ have?  Can you describe what the columns of $A$ are?  If it's helpful, you can let $I$ denote the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: wouldn't $A$ be an $m\times m$ identity matrix? Or rather a block matrix of identity matrices? (Where each column is an $n\times n$ identity matrix?

Comment: okay, so I give up - I have no idea what $A$ is supposed to be.ive tried a bunch of things, but nothing has given me back $y_{1}+y_{2}+\cdots + y_{m}$

Comment: @ALannister When you said "rather a block matrix of identity matrices" where each column is an $n \times n$ identity matrix, you were exactly right.  $A = \begin{bmatrix} I & \cdots & I \end{bmatrix}$ where the $n \times n$ identity matrix $I$ has been repeated $m$ times.  You are correct.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, though...

Comment: @ALannister How so? If we take this $A$ and multiply it by the column vector $y$ that we get by stacking the column vectors $y_1,\ldots, y_m$, don't we get $y_1+\cdots +y_m$?

Comment: Never mind, it does. Okay, so polar cone consists of all $A^T=\begin{pmatrix} I \\ I \\ \vdots \\I \end{pmatrix}\lambda$ such that $\lambda \in D^{\circ}$. But then,how do I figure out what $\lambda$ is?

Comment: At this point, I think you are done. That's the answer. The polar of $K_2$ has now been expressed in terms of the polar of $D$. But notice that $A^T \lambda$ is the vector that you get by stacking $m$ copies of $\lambda$. It's interesting to see that this description of $K_2^\circ$ is consistent with the conjecture we made in the earlier approach that we took to this problem.

Comment: I can't even begin to thank you enough! You're a saint, you know that?

Comment: @ALannister No problem, this was a good problem and it was good for me to learn about the theorem that we used. I also ended up ordering the textbook that you mentioned. Haha.

Comment: I currently have a 150 point bounty on this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449506/determine-the-polar-cone-of-the-convex-cone In the body of the question, I have 90% of an answer, and I went about it by using Farkas' Lemma, which is a corollary to the theorem we used here. If you could take a look, I'd very much appreciate it, considering how awesome you were here. Plus, there's 150 points.

Answer (score 0):

The result follows from mostly formal cone calculations.

It is straightforward to show that if $K$ is a cone and $L$ a linear operator then
$(LK)^\circ = (L^T)^{-1} K^\circ$.

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix} I \cdots I \end{bmatrix}$, then $K_2 = A^{-1} D$. Note that this is the inverse in a set valued sense, $A$ is not
injective.

Note that this gives $A^{-1} D = \ker A + A^\dagger D $, where $A^\dagger$ is
the pseudo inverse of $A$.

Also note that $(\ker A)^\circ = {\cal R} A^T $ since $\ker A$ is
a subspace.

Note that $A^\dagger y = {1 \over n} A^Ty$, and so $A^\dagger D = A^T D$.

If $A,B$ are closed convex cones then $(A+B)^\circ = A^\circ \cap  B^\circ$.

Hence $K_2^\circ = (\ker A)^\circ \cap (A^T D)^\circ = {\cal R} A^T \cap (A^T D)^\circ = {\cal R} A^T \cap A^{-1} D^\circ$.

Noting that ${\cal R} A^T = \{ (y,\cdots, y) \}_{y \in \mathbb{R}^n}$,
we see that
$K_2^\circ = \{ (y,\cdots, y) | y \in D^\circ \} = A^T D^\circ$.

Comment: Is there a standard name for the fact that $(LK)^\circ = (L^T)^{-1} K^\circ$?  I know it's related to Farkas' lemma.

Comment: I'm not aware of a name. The result follows from Formal manipulations, Farka's lemma is a much stronger result.